# Trouble answering calls on Motorola G

Tags: motorola-moto-g

When my phone rings my screen is black - to unlock I have to press the button on the lefthand side which then ends the call.It used to automatically show the caller id but since an update I am unable to answer any calls :(. Hope some-one is able to help me please. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

First go to `Settings -> Apps -> Disabled`(Tab). If you can find Dialer or Phone please enable it and then check after restarting your phone.

If your Phone/Dialer app is not disabled then try these steps,

1. Settings -> Apps -> All(Tab) -> Dialer
2. Clear Cache and Clear Data
3. Disable it and restart phone and Re-enable the Dialer app.

If problem persists you can for emergency purpose attend calls using your motorola headset.

Comment: Thank you for your help. My phone is now working properly. I appreciated your help.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, without proper logcat pointing to exact bug is difficult. But it could be a rom bug most likely.

Anyway, you can go to `Settings->Acessbility` and there somewhere in calls options should be an option `Power button ends calls` disable it and your power button will no longer cut calls on power button press.

Comment: Thanks - but didn't work