# Unable to pick the calls after upgrading to Lollipop 5.0.2

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, calls, micromax-yu-yureka

Yesterday I got an update to upgrade my Micromax Yureka mobile to CyanogenMod 12 which upgrades the Android version to Lollipop 5.0.2. And since then I am unable to pick calls, as nothing gets displayed/or rather display won't turn on to pick up the call.

Comment: Can you hear the ringtone while receving the calls? and Does this happen only when receiving incoming calls? Have you restarted the phone and checked? Try my other [answer over here](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/110641/27149) it may help solve your issue

Comment: i have done but no use, i am able to here ring tone but its showing black sceen, not able to see the screen and not able to pic the cal